# BIRT 4.7. Preview is not working on Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers 2018 with BIRT 4.7.
Preview is not working. 
Got following error when previewing report.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/Decorator ?
```

Please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: @greg-449 didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to update BIRT version to 4.8
Follow below steps,

1. Go to **Help** in the Eclipse menu bar and select **Install New Software**
2. Click Add button
3. Add this URL to *Location*

   http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/photon-interim/

[image]

4. Finally, update the Eclipse by **Help -> Check for updates**

Comment: Nice!  I no longer get this error after this fix, but get "java.awt.HeadlessException" after I  try to render any type of report. Time to switch to a different BI tool that is not silly.